# Konsole --new-tab: choose which existing konsole instance

Tags: linux, command-line, scripting, gnome-terminal, konsole

I usually have several *konsole* windows on several desktops.

Running *konsole --new-tab* is intended to open a new tab in an existing window, but it seems never goes to the window I want. This is really boring.

In fact it seems to go to the first *konsole* instance launched while I would expect it to go to the *last one* launched (the way *gnome-terminal --tab* is supposed to work, but it doesn't seem to work on mt system, *CentOS 6*).

*--session* doesn't help.

Any solution?